# Combaning Multiple plots into a Single plot

Tags: r, plot, dataframe

I am writing a code to generate four stimulations and then generate graphs. My code works, but I want instead of generating four graphs I want to combine them all in one graph. How can I do that?

My code:

```
queueSimulation <- function(arriverate, servrate, endtime) {
    queue = numeric(0)
    arrivetimes = rexp(10000, arriverate)
    servtimes = rexp(10000, servrate)

    clock = 0.0 
    clist=c() 
    qlist=c()
    while(clock <= endtime) {
       if(length(queue) > 0 && queue[1] < arrivetimes[1]) {
          clock = clock + queue[1]
          queue = queue[-1]   
       }   
       else {
          clock = clock + arrivetimes[1]
          queue[length(queue) + 1] = servtimes[1]
          arrivetimes = arrivetimes[-1]
          servtimes = servtimes[-1]
       }   

    #queue_size= length(round(clock, 2))
       clist = c(clist , clock)
       qlist = c(qlist , length(queue))
    }   
    a<-data.frame(time=clist , qsize=qlist)
    print(a)
    mean1<-mean(qlist)
    cat("Average :", mean1, "\n")
    plot(a)
}
```

and calling the function:

```
queueSimulation(1.0, 5.0, 100) 
queueSimulation(2.0, 4.0, 100)
queueSimulation(2.3, 3.5, 100) 
queueSimulation(4.0, 5.0, 100)
```

Comment: in my opinion it is best to separate the plotting step from the data accumulation. So I would suggest that you collect the data frames by running your function several times, e.g. in a list, and only then plot all the data (e.g with matplot). This way you won't get into trouble of having to rescale axes, etc. Is there a specific reason to add lines in a chronological sequence like your question suggests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a better solution to this, but how about slightly changing your approach.

1- In your function, add two variables, one for color (cl) and one to tell your function if your plotting the main plot or just adding lines (pl). 1 for main and 0 for lines.

```
function(arriverate, servrate, endtime,cl,pl) {
```

2- call your plot with an if statement, and fix your y axis to range from 0 to 200.

```
if(pl==1){plot(a,col=cl,ylim=c(0,200),type="l")} else{lines(a,col=cl)}}
```

and then, call your function with theses two variables (cl and pl) :

```
queueSimulation(1.0, 5.0, 100,"red",1)  
queueSimulation(2.0, 4.0, 100,"blue",0)  
queueSimulation(2.3, 3.5, 100,"green",0)  
queueSimulation(4.0, 5.0, 100,"black",0)
```

The problem I see with this is that your simulations can get values way over 200 for the y axis, maybe try to find a way to get max y values in one of your call.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `layout`, specifically put `layout(matrix(1:4,nrow=2))` (or a variant) before you call your plotting functions.